# magento product image returns 404

Tags: php, magento, nginx, media

I’m fresh install Nginx + PHP5.4 + Magento 1.9.1 + Theme. I upload a product with image. The image can not be show in frontend. 
The url like

```
http://www.example.com/media//650x/d/e/desk1_2.jpg
```

can not be accessed. But url

```
http://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/d/e/desk1_2.jpg
```

is ok. Nginx log shows that

```
GET /skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/infortis/_shared/cck/list/bullet.png HTTP/1.1” 200 172 “http://www.domain.com/media//650x/d/e/desk1_2.jpg
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that its the problem about MVentory_S3CDN plugin. I install this plguin without setting. It's ok while I delete the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Magento's default themes resize the product images before showing them. This involves saving the resized images in the `media/catalog/product/cache` directory. Most likely, your file permissions are not set up correctly, and Magento fails to write the resized image files to the drive, resulting in missing images. Double check your permissions and make sure Magento can write into the `media` directory.